# Selenium. Ошибка при использовании Profile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, profile

Не понимаю в чём заключается ошибка, Он запускает браузер с профилем и выдаёт ошибку.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir')
        options.add_argument('--enable-profile-shortcut-manager')
        options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\Костьян\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(r'C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\VK REPOST\vk_bot_repost_V2\chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.get('https://vk.com')
        time.sleep(1000)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\VK REPOST\vk_bot_repost_V2\test_PROFILE.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(r'C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\VK REPOST\vk_bot_repost_V2\chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 363, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0070ACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x0069EE61+1633889]
    Ordinal0 [0x0059B7BD+571325]
    Ordinal0 [0x005BAA93+699027]
    Ordinal0 [0x005B6BE9+682985]
    Ordinal0 [0x005EDBD3+908243]
    Ordinal0 [0x005ED6AA+906922]
    Ordinal0 [0x005E7136+880950]
    Ordinal0 [0x005BFEFD+720637]
    Ordinal0 [0x005C0F3F+724799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009BEED2+2769538]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009B0D95+2711877]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0079A03A+521194]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00798DA0+516432]
    Ordinal0 [0x006A682C+1665068]
    Ordinal0 [0x006AB128+1683752]
    Ordinal0 [0x006AB215+1683989]
    Ordinal0 [0x006B6484+1729668]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74F2FEF9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770B7BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770B7B8E+238]
```

Answer (score 0):

Это я с другого аккаунта, проблема была в том что был открыт браузер в момент работы кода.